# Subform values are showing up as null on the receiving end after form submit

Tags: forms, symfony, subform

I have built out a form which submits fine, however subform values all end up as null on the receiving end when I look at them in the controller.

Here is my `UserProfileType` form, based on the `User`class.  So specifically, the subforms we are looking at are `subscriptionTier1`, `subscriptionTier1`, and `subscriptionTier1`:

```
class UserProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)

            // etc... I'll keep out the unimportant fields

            // here are the subforms whose values show up as null on the back end
            ->add('subscriptionTier1', UserSubscriptionTierType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false
                ])
            ->add('subscriptionTier2', UserSubscriptionTierType::class, [
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => false
                ])
            ->add('subscriptionTier3', UserSubscriptionTierType::class, [
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => false
                ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'save'],
            ])
        ;

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'mode' => null
        )
    );
}
```

}

Here is what my `UserSubscriptionTierType` form type class looks like:

```
class UserSubscriptionTierType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'maxlength' => 25
                ]
            ])
            ->add('price', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    '$10 per month' => 10,
                    '$20 per month' => 20,
                    '$30 per month' => 30
                ]
            ])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('messaging', CheckboxType::class, [
                'required' => false
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => UserSubscriptionTier::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

As you can see in the picture below, the subform subscriptionTier1's name, price, and description values are all set on the front-end:

[image]

Here is what the twig code looks like for the `subscriptionTier1` subform:

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center w-100 ml-0 mr-0 mt-3 tier tier-1" >
        <div class="col-lg-6 mt-1">
            <div class="form-group form-control-lg w-100">
                <label for="firstname" class="mb-2">Tier 1 Name</label>
                {{ form_widget(form.subscriptionTier1.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 mt-1">
            <div class="form-group form-control-lg w-100">
                <label for="tier1price" class="mb-2">Tier 1 Price</label>
                {{ form_widget(form.subscriptionTier1.price, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 mt-3">
            <div class="form-group form-control-lg w-100">
                <label for="bio" class="mb-2">Tier 1 Description
                    <sup class="text-danger">*</sup>
                </label>
                {{ form_widget(form.subscriptionTier1.description, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control border-box', 'rows':'8'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group form-control-lg w-100">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        {{ form_widget(form.subscriptionTier1.messaging, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control form-check-input'}}) }}
                        <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                        Enable Messaging
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the code on the receiving end, the controller:

```
public function saveProfileAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $form = $this->createForm(UserProfileType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

dump($form->get('subscriptionTier1')->getData());
```

So in debugging, if I dump just the first form `subscriptionTier1`, you can see that the values are all `null`.

```
ProfileController.php on line 269:
Form {#2235 ▼
  -config: FormBuilder {#2236 ▶}
  -parent: Form {#2112 ▶}
  -children: OrderedHashMap {#2237 ▶}
  -errors: []
  -submitted: true
  -clickedButton: null
  -modelData: UserSubscriptionTier {#2280 ▼
    -id: null
    -posts: ArrayCollection {#2323 ▶}
    -subscriptions: null
    -name: null         // Don't understand why this is null 
    -price: null        // Don't understand why this is null 
    -description: null  // Don't understand why this is null 
    -tierNumber: null
    -versionNumber: null
    -messaging: false
    -user: null
    +"subsciptions": ArrayCollection {#2089 ▶}
  }
  -normData: UserSubscriptionTier {#2280 ▶}
  -viewData: UserSubscriptionTier {#2280 ▶}
  -extraData: []
  -transformationFailure: null
  -defaultDataSet: true
  -lockSetData: false
}
```

Would anyone know why the values are not passing to the back-end (or getting nulled out)?

Comment: If it's not in `Request` object (you may also check raw `$_POST` data for sure), then you should check the rendered HTML. If data doesn't come with request, there's not much you can do on backend side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `data_class` option of `UserProfileType` form type is set to `User` class, the model data will be an instance of `User` class and since the `User` class doesn't have fields like `subscriptionTier1` etc, these will not appear in your model data.

Instead, you could access unmapped fields in a form in a controller like this:

```
$subscriptionTier1 = $form->get('subscriptionTier1')->getData();
```

Documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

EDIT: You can only access the value of subscriptionTier1 etc, only after the form has been handled and only if the form has been submitted, otherwise it will be null:

```
public function saveProfileAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $form = $this->createForm(UserProfileType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $subscriptionTier1 = $form->get('subscriptionTier1')->getData();
        dump($subscriptionTier1);
    }
```

Comment: Hi iirxs, thanks that was a big help.  Now the form values are all null.  I'll have to edit the question.  But that was still a big help.

Comment: I have edited my answer to help you understand it better

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is just a workaround or of this is actually the best practices way to do it, but here's how I got it to work:

I had the following subform tags in:

    `{{ form_start(form.subscriptionTier1) }} 
    etc... 
    {{ form_end(form.subscriptionTier1) }}`

This will nest form tags.  Apparently you are not allowed to nest forms like this.

So taking out the `{{ form_start(form.subscriptionTier1) }}` , `{{ form_end(form.subscriptionTier1) }}` for all the `subscriptionTier1`, `subscriptionTier1`, `subscriptionTier1`and then checking for the form values in the request object worked.